# Recommended tools for Theme Development with SASS

Tags: theme-development, themes, html-editor, sass

**My question is** - what are other people's processes in most efficiently developing WordPress themes that utilize SASS and what tools are you using? I also develop from multiple locations/machines (both Windows/OSX) so I would like to have my dev environment stored centrally.

**A bit about my requirements** -
I work for a web development business and would like to start developing my own WP themes with SASS but I can't find a clear solution on what tools I should be using.

Normally my development environments reside on a subdomain I create off my website which I password protect/hide from Google etc. This works well because not only does it free up my PC's resources (compared to if I was building it locally) but I can access the dev environment from any machine.

That being the case (wanting my dev environments to not be stored locally), I am more than happy to use the code editor tools offered in cPanel to modify the files directly on the site however I am wanting to start using SASS which requires compiling, which from what I assume needs to be done locally.

Thanks!

Comment: There are plenty developer tools, free and paid, it is up to find the one which works best for you. I personally use XAMMP for windows with notepad++ for by local test install :-)

Comment: I came across just before reading the question: http://www.vandelaydesign.com/wordpress-developer-tools/ But it is just personal opinion.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a WordPress theme development environment in Windows VPS. You'll need the following tools:

**Text Editors**

- Aptana Studio 3
- Netbeans
- Notepad++

**Local WordPress Development Environments**

- XAMPP
- InstantWP

**Debugging Tools**

- Firebug
- Theme Check
- Debug Bar

**Plugin & Theme Development Tools**

- Theme Demo Bar
- Responsive Select Menu
- Less & Sass
- PressTrends
- Font Awesome

Answer (score 0):

@adambock - Below I am going to provide you a link which I found very valuable resource for all WordPress related tools. Just providing link is not allowed here and more details are expected from the person who is providing a solution. So my solution may get deleted. But I don't think there is much to mention because the below link has all valuable info/links.

Here you go: http://wpgear.org/